# Typescript type for `React.createContext(null)` when using null for initial value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, react-context, use-context

I have this hook that I use to get the value from a `useContext`

**useFirebase.js**

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';

export const FirebaseContext = React.createContext(null);

function useFirebase(): firebase.app.App {
  const firebase = useContext(FirebaseContext);
  return firebase;
}

export default useFirebase;
```

This is the context provider:

**App.js**

```
import { FirebaseContext } from '@hooks/useFirebase';

function App() {
  return(
    <FirebaseContext.Provider value={props.firebase}>
      // The app
    </FirebaseContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Then I access throughout the app by doing:

**SomeComponent.ts**

```
const firebase = useFirebase();
```

**THE PROBLEM**

In the `useFirebase.ts` file, I'm having trouble between `null` that is initialized in the `React.createContext(null)`

[image]

How can I get rid of this conflict?

**Note:** `props.firebase` type is `firebase.app.App`

I usually call `createContext` with `null` and that is why Typescript is complaining about.

The following code seems to do the trick, but I don't want to use `{}` instead of null.

`export const FirebaseContext = React.createContext({} as firebase.app.App);`

Comment: Have you tried `createContext<App | null>(null)`?

Answer (score 3):

Try typing `createContext`:

```
const FirebaseContext = React.createContext<firebase.app.App | null>(null);
```

For a more useful information see [React TS Cheatsheet](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/context#docsNav).